# UWP XamlParseException AccessDenied Can't find a Resource

Tags: xaml, uwp, access-denied, xamlparseexception

It appears that somehow my Visual Studio instance has lost access permissions to the ThemeResources XAML file...?
In design view, I get the following error:
**An Unhandled Exception has occurred**

Click here to reload the designer
Click here to only display platform controls and reload the designer (this may improve stability)
Learn more
Details:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT:0X80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)
I can still build and deploy the app locally but the first time the application tries to load a ThemeResource (whether from the SDK or a Nuget package), it blows up with the following message:
**Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException:** 'The text associated with this error code could not be found.
Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key TextControlBorderBrush [Line: 798 Position: 44]
Initially that message referenced a resource used by the NavigationView, but I commented that control out and got this message instead.

This is a problem on my existing application on this device as well as any new blank UWP apps I create.
Now, I don't control this laptop so I don't know what all has been done to it.  Everything I do on the internet has to travel through my employer's VPN and they've made some changes over the last week to handle all of the new WFH traffic.  I started to install VS2019 on here a week ago but "Paused" the install never got to finish.  This error prompted me to finish the install in hopes that it would fix the problem, but it did not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: About this sentence "I can still build and deploy the app locally", do you mean the xaml designer can't display xaml layout and throw those exception, but when you run your app, it all worked well?

Comment: No...unfortunately.  After the app is deployed, as soon as it's opened it immediately throws the XamlParseException mentioned in the OP as it tries to find the 1st Resource it needs.

Comment: If each of your new blank uwp app you create will throw XamlParseException, it may indicate that there is something wrong with VS. You could try to repair your VS or reinstall it.